# Need / consumption of magnesium

Tags: human-biology, muscles, nutrition

Does doing sports makes a human require more magnesium and – if any – how strong is this effect?

Do athletes take magnesium supplements (e.g. pills of magnesium carbonate) because they build muscles and therefore need more of it as their muscle masses increase, or is magnesium consumed by muscle activity (e.g. by causing a chemical reaction which the human body can't undo so it has to excrete the reaction product and get new magnesium from food)?

Comment: @Xaqron You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Strenuous exercise apparently increases urinary and sweat losses that may increase magnesium requirements by 10-20% according to [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17172008) paper.

Comment: Is magnesium stored in muscles / do you need more when gaining muscles?

Comment: @UTF-8: You are correct. Please check [here](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/Magnesium-HealthProfessional) for more info.

Comment: I don't see how the linked page says anything about where magnesium is stored or whether you need more of it if your muscle mass increases.

Comment: @UTF-8: Your assumption is true and the like contains a table for magnesium needs in different ages/gender. According to table 0.5 gr/day is maximum someone may need.

Answer (score 0):

Sweat and kidneys remove magnesium.  Some foods and medicines retain potassium. Exercise will move salts indiscriminately.  Kidneys try to keep a balance.